# how to add the existed iOS DocSet to xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, docset

I have already downloaded the iOS 6.1 DocSet, as shown here in Finder when I navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/`:

[image: DocSets in Finder]

But, when in Xcode preferences it prompts me to `Install` it again, even though it's already been downloaded:

[image: Xcode preferences]

How can I make Xcode read the already installed DocSet?

Comment: How about just clicking button *check and install?*

Comment: Once I did not have iOS 6.1 library installed and still it showed installed, I clicked that button and it showed not installed.

Comment: @rohan-patel thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: @rohan-patel I just look into the .docset and right clicked the 'show package contents' then in the 'documents' directory it's empty may be that's why they should downloaded.